# Add different version of opencv

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to do EigenFace Face Recognition in Opencv 3.0.0 but the module is present in Modules which I have to build the opencv again. Can I have different account in linux machine with different opencv version? Does different accounts can have different libraries?

Comment: You don't even need different accounts. Libraries are just files

Comment: so if I want to install different version in different account, it will not interfere with each other ?

Comment: You can install as many versions you want to anything. Libraries usually have version numbers in their filenames and if not, you can just put them in different directories. But you can't install a precompiled version if it doesn't have proper versioned naming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some libraries support have different versions deployed at the same time, but most do not, in this case, you will need to install the alternative into an isolated environment, for example, a mock build or chroot. But there is another approach too, use containers, you can have several containers running with the same base image, just install your required opencv on top of them.